# Backwards typing in TexStudio after backslash

Tags: texstudio, editors

I searched for an answer to this, but couldn't find anything (or even a good way to describe it). The problem is this. Often, though not always, when I type a command in Texstudio, the command ends up backwards. And I have no idea why, nor how to stop it. It only started a few days ago, before that it never happened.

For example, suppose I want to type in maths mode `\alpha` (with the space after). I'll press all the keys in order, and the editor will spit out `\ ahpla` (with the space between the backslash and ahpla). Or if I want to type `\in`, I'll get `\ ni`.

As far as I can tell, I'm not pressing any special combination of keys to make this happen. And I didn't change anything in settings. Occurrence seems random.

Comment: What TeXstudio version and OS are you using? When does the reversal happen? After pressing the space key? Do you have any macros set? Because this does not seem like normal behavior.

Comment: Sounds as if you are inserting Unicode 202E (https://xkcd.com/1137/). In windows the keyboard layout can change after pressing Alt+shift and then suddendlz y come out as z. Perhaps you have something similar.

Comment: I know this problem from TXS 2.12.6 on OSX. I don't think the problem is connected to keyboard layouts (I only have the US layout installed), but my impression is that the problem lies somewhere in the automatic detection of Right-to-Left characters. Unfortunately I have not yet been able to find a reproducible trigger for this problem.

Comment: I did not experience this problem in previous TXS versions, but this could be a coincidence.

Comment: @Troy TeXstudio 2.12.6, Windows 10 Home v 1709. I doubt it has anything to do with the OS though. As noted in the original post, the reversal happens *sometimes* after pressing backslash. e.g., if I want to type `\alpha `, I'll get `\a` then `\la` then `\pla`, and so on, up until the point that I've got `\ ahpla` at which point it seems to return to normal.

Comment: related bug report: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/87

Comment: To those that don't frequent github (and face this issue), apparantly the issue is fixed now: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/87#issuecomment-382818202. Try the snapshots (>git afd3df8) from https://bintray.com/sunderme/texstudio.

Comment: @Troy Please consider converting your comment in an answer, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7008/36296

Comment: @samcarter Ok will do in a bit. Having lunch now :)

Comment: @Troy Bon appétit! (but only if you're not having duck)

Comment: @samcarter Done, thanks! And no, not eating duck :) Not the cute yellow ones anyway. :p

Comment: @Troy Thank you for your answer and for not eating cute yellow ducks :)

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour was also reported in the Github issue tracker for TeXstudio, and is now [fixed](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/87#issuecomment-382818202) in the Github repository, as of **TXS 2.12.9 (git afd3df8)**.

Until this is included in the next official release however (currently, the stable release is TXS 2.12.8), you may either compile TXS yourself or,

- for OSX and Win: download snapshots (> `git_afd3df8`) from [here](http://bintray.com/sunderme/texstudio), under the "Files" tab;
- for Ubuntu: see instructions [here](https://launchpad.net/~sunderme/+archive/ubuntu/texstudio-daily). Basically:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunderme/texstudio-daily
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

If the issue is not fully resolved, leave a comment here, but more importantly, continue the conversation on Github issues (i.e., report it to the devs as well).